# Ngrx entity (data) multiple entity delete wrong types included for a rest backend

Tags: java, backend, entity, ngrx

I am currently struggling with deleting multiple entities and the save multiple entities pattern in NgRx. Here is the current problem:

My UI EntityCacheService:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PlayerService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Player> {

  changes: ChangeSetItem[] = [];

  constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory,
              private entityCacheDispatcher: EntityCacheDispatcher) {
    super('Player', serviceElementsFactory);
  }

  public createPlayerToBatch(players: Player) {
    let cs = new ChangeSetItemFactory().add("Player", players);
    this.changes.push(cs);
  }

  public updatePlayerToBatch(players: Player) {
    let cs = new ChangeSetItemFactory().update<Player>("Player", {id: players.id, changes: players});
    this.changes.push(cs);
  }

  // TODO: wrong type in backend here ...
  public deletePlayerToBatch(players: Player) {
    let cs = new ChangeSetItemFactory().delete("Player", players.id.toString());
    this.changes.push(cs);
  }

  public resetChanges() {
    this.changes = [];
  }

  public saveChangesToDatabase() {
    console.log("ChangeSetItems: ", this.changes);

    if(this.changes.length == 0) {
      // no changes
    }

    // https://blog.angular-university.io/ngrx-entity/
    this.entityCacheDispatcher.saveEntities(this.changes, environment.baseURL + 'player/crud/dispatcher')
        .pipe(
            map(response => response)
        );
  }
```

My Rest Endpoint looks like:

```
@POST
    @Path("player/crud/dispatcher")
    public Response multipleCrudDispatcher(ChangeSet<Player> cs) {

        ChangeItem<Player>[] items;
        items = cs.getChanges();

        Arrays.stream(items).forEach(changeItem -> {

            // Get alle affected entities from change item
            switch (changeItem.getOp()) {
                case Add:
                    System.out.println("ADD");
                    // Make the update database logic
                    handelAdd(changeItem.getEntities());
                    break;
                case Delete:
                    System.out.println("DELETE" );
                    // Make the update database logic
                    //handelDelete((String[]) changeItem.getEntities());
                    break;
                case Update:
                    System.out.println("UPDATE");
                    // Make the update database logic
                    handelUpdates(changeItem.getEntities());
                    break;
                case Upsert:
                    System.out.println("UPSERT");

                    break;
                default:

            }
        });

        return Response.ok(cs).build();
    }
```

The endpoint expects a changeSet of type "Player" in the backend, the same structure that comes from the frontend. This works also with create, upsert, update all very well, because they also contain a list of player objects. But with DELETE it doesn't work :-(. The DELETE expects an ID list with strings or numbers ... which leads to an error in the backend, because Java tries to create a player object. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this unsightly problem?